# why is it true for a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I fail to see why for 2 vectors $a,b$ and a symmetric matrix C:
$$ aCb = bCa $$
It is clear that $ aCb = (bCa)^T$, but why is it true without the transpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $a,b$ are column vectors. (In your writing, $a$ is a row vector and $b$ is a column vector. This would be unusual in linear algebra.)

Then one consideres $a^TCb$.

By transposition, $(a^TCb)^T  = b^T C^T a = b^T C a$, when $C$ is symmetric.

Since $a^TCb = (a^TCb)^T$ as the result is a scalar, we obtain

$a^TCb = b^T C a$.

Comment: Thank you! You clarified the logical step I was missing.

Comment: @Wuestenfux - Can you expand further on what you mean by "as the result is a scalar"?

Comment: @nwaldo: $a^TCb$ is a $1x1$ matrix.